# When Instagram user has deauthorized my app with deauthorization callback url, deauthorize callback sending me a different user id

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

For Authorizing Instagram with my App, I have followed

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started

For deauthorization Instagram from the App, deauthorization callback

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started#deauthorize-callback-url

The issue I am facing is that I am getting different User Ids for same Instagram account upon deauthorize callback. When a Instagram user remove my client app from their account then Instagram sent a signed_request through the deauthorize callback url. After parsing the signed_request. We are getting different user id against that user!!!

Note: I am using a tester user for my client app

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug describing this exact problem here:
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1485832065259000/?join_id=f290dd8c434813c

The StackOverflow answer from Krishna Poddar says:

> So, to solve this issue, while authorizing, also fetch user graph id along with user api id that you can match later on while deauthorizing

Unless I'm missing something, there doesn't seem to be any option in the Basic Display API to "fetch user graph id" as Krishna suggested.

You can get the correct user ID with a new API call after getting the ID returned from the deauthorization callback in order to get the correct user ID:

```
https://graph.instagram.com/{user_id from callback}?fields=id&access_token={access_token}
```

However, this doesn't help unless you already know which user_id the graph id belongs to in order to use the correct access token in this API call (which is what we are trying to find out!).

I'm hoping someone else has solved this issue and will come along and comment, but as yet there seems to be no working solutions to this very annoying issue.

The response from the Meta Team in the bug report is fairly useless:

> *We just got back from our team and this is unfortunately a won't fix for now and will be considered for a fix in future. I'm sorry for any disappointment this may cause. I do understand how important this is for you, and I made sure to share your feedback with the team as well.*
>
> *We'll keep tracking the issue internally for a possible fix in the future. Please let me know if you have any other questions in the meantime. Thanks for your patience.*

I'd love anyone else who has had this issue to comment and would be more than happy to be proved wrong!

Comment: I just ran into this. But if Facebook/Meta decides they "won't fix" this then they also can't expect me to implement it.

Comment: @nickdnk I agree, I haven't implemented it as it seems impossible right now!

Answer (score 0):

You're using Instagram Basic Display API and while authorizing the request, you'll get api id's (User id's) but when deauthorizing, the callback returns user graph id that is graph id and not api id which you got while authorizing before.
So, to solve this issue, while authorizing, also fetch user graph id along with user api id that you can match later on while deauthorizing